# How to locate a row whose id is dynamic

Tags: java, selenium

```
<table id="SlotTable" class="noborder" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" paging="false" style="border-top: 0px none; table-layout: fixed; width: 984px;">
<tbody id="tableBody">
<script>
<tr id="97.115.104.105.115.104.50" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">
<tr id="97.115.104.105.115.104.49" style="background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);">
<tr id="97.115.104.105.115.104" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">
<tr id="97.115.104.105.115.104.51" style="background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);">
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to access row id so that i can select it and then delete that row,but id of the row is changing dynamically so someone please help me in accessing the row.If i will add new row then new id will be generated.In the above code 4 rows has been added.

Comment: A possible solution would be to select the row based on its index. That is to select the parent, the table, and then loop through its children, the rows, until you find one you want then delete it.

Comment: but the condition through which i will check which row to delete is based on its content.So how can i locate the row and then its content.sorry i am totally new to selenium web driver.please help

Comment: actually the row which i want to delete that i will select from an application and that can be any first or third or any.the above code that i have pasted is copied from firebug addon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate row using xpath:

```
//tbody[@id='tableBody']//tr[1]
```

or

```
//tbody[@id='tableBody']/script/tr[1]
```

Change number to access the row you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to select the row on table.

```
#<Enter ID> or .<Class name> tr:nth-child("row index")
```

Example:

```
CSS= #idname tr:nth-child(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the row if some part of the ID generated will be constant.

> If you id is 97.115.104.105.115.104.50 and here 97.115 is constant and unique then use an xpath like
> //tbody[@id = 'tableBody']//tr[contains(@id, '97.115')]
>
> This will return the row in which this combination of values are there.